# To delete queries! I've tried with the posts already available. It didn't work.

Tags: php

My first page to delete queries selected by user `query.php` which is working absolutely fine:

```
<form method=post  action="delete.php"> 
List of queries<br/>
<?php
$ebits = ini_get('error_reporting');
error_reporting($ebits ^ E_NOTICE);
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("testdb") or die(mysql_error());
echo "<br />";
$query = "select * from queries ";
$result =  mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{ 
print "<input type='checkbox' name='Query[]' value=\"".$row['queryId']."\"> "; 
echo "     ". $row['name']."      ". $row["address"]."           ". $row["contactNo"]."   

      ". $row["query"];
echo "<br />"; 
}  
?>
<input type="submit" value="Delete" name="Delete"> 
<br/>  
</form>
```

I've tried with following codes for second page `delete.php` but nothing seems to work.
   Code1:

```
<?php
if($_POST['Delete'])  
{  
if(count($_POST['checkbox']) > 0) {  
   foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox)  
   {  
        $del_id=$checkbox;  
        $sql = "DELETE * FROM queries WHERE `queryId`= '$del_id'";  
        $result = mysql_query($sql);  
        mysql_error();  

   }  
   echo "Selected Rows deleted";  
} else {  
     $NEW="Nothing to Delete";  
}

}
?>
```

Code2:

```
<?php
if(($_POST['Delete']))
{
$count=array();
$count=$_POST['checkbox'];
for($i=0;$i<count($count);$i++){
        $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM queries WHERE queryId='$del_id' ";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
$NEW="Selected records Deleted";
}
var_dump($_POST['checkbox']);
var_dump($count);

?>
```

Comment: I finding problems about the second page which will be used to delete the selected queries.

Answer (score 2):

Your checkbox names are "Query", but you're accessing it as `$_POST['checkbox']`. This should be `$_POST['Query']` instead.

**EDIT** checking from your updated code:

```
if($_POST['Delete']) { 
  if(count($_POST['Query']) > 0) { 
    foreach($_POST['Query'] as $checkbox) { 
      $del_id=$checkbox; 
      $sql = "DELETE * FROM queries WHERE queryId= '$del_id'"; 
      $result = mysql_query($sql); 
      mysql_error(); 
    } 
    echo "Selected Rows deleted"; 
  } 
  else { 
    $NEW="Nothing to Delete"; 
  } 
}
```

Instead of this:

```
$del_id=$checkbox;
```

do this:

```
// if queryId is numeric
$del_id=intval($checkbox);
```

This makes sure that the value you're working with is numeric, instead of potential malicious input from your user. I'm going under the assumption that `queryId` is numeric. If it's not, then  you need to do this:

```
// if queryId is not numeric:
$del_id = mysql_real_escape_string($checkbox);
```

Your `DELETE` syntax is incorrect:

```
$sql = "DELETE * FROM queries WHERE queryId= '$del_id'";
```

You want just `DELETE FROM`. Also if the value for queryId is numeric, you don't need the quotes around it:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `queries` WHERE `queryId` = $del_id";
```

Finally, your MySQL error call doesn't do anything useful as is:

```
mysql_error();
```

Here's how you should do this, along with the rest of the code:

```
if($_POST['Delete']) { 
  if(count($_POST['Query']) > 0) { 
    foreach($_POST['Query'] as $checkbox) { 
      $del_id= intval($checkbox); 
      $sql = "DELETE FROM `queries` WHERE `queryId` = $del_id"; 
      $result = mysql_query($sql); 
      if(!$result) {
        echo "There was an error in the query: " . mysql_error();
      }
    } 
    echo "Selected Rows deleted"; 
  } 
  else { 
    $NEW="Nothing to Delete"; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: <?php
if($_POST['Delete'])  
{  
if(count($_POST['Query']) > 0) {  
   foreach($_POST['Query'] as $checkbox)  
   {  
        $del_id=$checkbox;  
        $sql = "DELETE * FROM queries WHERE `queryId`= '$del_id'";  
        $result = mysql_query($sql);  
        mysql_error();  

   }  
   echo "Selected Rows deleted";  
} else {  
     $NEW="Nothing to Delete";  
}

}
?>